# JavaScript jQuery pass value returned from service

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.onload = initializeSpeciesMap();
    getSpeciesList();

    $("#btnSpecies").click(function () {
        alert($("#speciesList").val());
        addMyMarker($("#speciesList").val());
    });
    });

    // get list of birds by species to populate the sayt
    function getSpeciesList() {
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("GET", "http://ebird.org/ws1.1/ref/taxa/ebird?      cat=species,hybrid&fmt=json&locale=en_US", true);
    ajax.onload = function () {
        var list = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText).map(function (i) { return i.comName + " - <p id='dt'> " + i.sciName + "</p>"; });
        new Awesomplete(document.querySelector("#speciesList"), { list: list });
        $(".input-loader").css("background-image", "none");
    };
    ajax.send();
}
```

That works and it returns me the following example in my html:

```
<li aria-selected="true"><mark>Osprey</mark><p id="dt"> - Pandion haliaetus</p></li>
```

I need to take that value and return only the "sciName" variable to another function....  I want both comName and the sciName to appear on my UI but I only want the sciName to pass on.

How can I get this value?  I hope this made sense.

The li is using awesomeplete for typeahead functionality....

Answer (score 0):

This is super ugly but it works..

```
        var species_str = $("#speciesList").val();
    var start_pos = species_str.indexOf('-') + 1;
    var end_pos = species_str.indexOf('-', start_pos);
    var scientificName = species_str.substring(start_pos, end_pos);
    alert($.trim(scientificName));
```